# Unwanted GET request in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a simple Angular Flickr Photo Feeder:
[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/xuanmmt/pen/NABwAd)

After searching for some tag, there is a list of returned `img-container` items displayed by ng-repeat. And at the very beginning, there should be no item in the list, thus there should be no `img-container` element.

However when starting the app, in the console it shows a 404 error (can't get `photo.media.m`,which is the `src` attribute of `img` element). This means there is at least one `img-container` element in the beginning.

Any thoughts, and how to prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-src` insetad of `src`. That way you won't get an error.

```
<img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{photo.media.m}}">
```

From the [official AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc):

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.